# C Segmentation Fault - linked lists

Tags: c, list, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I just started programming in C a few weeks ago and I am getting a segmentation fault in my program.

I believe it is because of those lines:

```
for (int i =0; i < HOW_MANY; i++) 
         {
        people = people -> next;
        if (people -> next == NULL) return people;
     } //for
      }//else
```

**Here is my C program with comments based on my psedocode**

```
struct person *insert_end (struct person *people, char *name, int age) {
//create a new space for the new person
  struct person *pointer = malloc(sizeof(struct person));
   // check it succeeded
    if(pointer == NULL)
    { 
     printf("The program could not allocate memory ");
      exit(-1);
    }
     // set the data for the new person
      strcpy(pointer -> name, name);
      pointer -> age = age;
      pointer -> next = people;
     // if the current list is empty
      if (people == NULL)
      {
        // set the new person's "next" link to point to the current list"
    pointer -> next = people;
    // return a pointer to the new person
    return pointer;
      }
      else  
      {
     // we need a loop to find the last item in the list 
    // (the one which as a "next" link of NULL)
         for (int i =0; i < HOW_MANY; i++) 
         {
       // set the "next link of this item to point
           // to the new person, so that the person
           // becomes the last item in the list
           // (the next person should have a "next" link of NULL)
        people = people -> next;
        if (people -> next == NULL)
        return people;
     } //for
      }//else
       // return the start of the list
       return pointer;    
}
```

***Also, let me know in case you need my full C code for the program, since this is only a method***

Thank you,

Sarah :)

Comment: Probably better suited for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: [Don't cast the return value of `malloc()!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)

Comment: you say `if (person == 0)` and `(*lastItem.next) = people;
` but there is no variables called person ad lastitem.  And there are other problems of that nature as well so it is hard o figure out what part you are having trouble with.

Comment: It's complicated by the fact that your pseudocode doesn't make it clear if you are trying to insert the new person at the beginning or end of the list.  First you ser the new person's next to the list putting it at the beginning and then you do a loop to find the end of the list - not to mention that when the list is empty you still point to it.

Answer (score 1):

This is totally a question for Code Review, but since you did ask a question regarding how to implement an algorithm, at least I think it is suitable for Stack Overflow.

For starters, this is just a syntax thing, but I think you should replace this:

`(*pointer).age = age;`

with this

`pointer -> age = age;`

This notation is a lot cleaner in my opinion, and was incorporated into C for the purpose of accessing elements from a struct pointer. Other than that the code you have so far is missing some closing braces. Here's a version of your code with proper syntax, and other important stuff (such as what @H2CO3 mentioned):

```
struct person *insert_end (struct person *people, char *name, int age) {

//create a new space for the new person
struct person *pointer = malloc(sizeof(struct person));

// check it succeeded
if(pointer == NULL)
{ 
    printf("The program could not allocate memory ");
    exit(-1);
}

// set the data for the new person
strcpy(pointer -> name, name);
pointer -> age = age;
pointer -> next = people;

// if the current list is empty
if (person == 0)
{
    // set the new person's "next" link to point to the current list"
    pointer -> next = people;

    // return a pointer to the new person
    return pointer;
}

else
{
    // we need a loop to find the last item in the list 
    // (the one which as a "next" link of NULL)
    for (int i =0; i < HOW_MANY; i++) 
    {
        // set the "next link of this item to point
        // to the new person, so that the person
        // becomes the last item in the list
        // (the next person should have a "next" link of NULL)
        lastItem -> next = people;
    }

    // return the start of the list
    return pointer;    
}

}
```

Lastly, since I don't have a full copy of your entire code, nor do I want it, I can provide you advice on how to implement the portion of pseudo-code you are unsure of.

> use a loop to find the last item in the list (i.e. the one which has a
>   "next" link of NULL)

Finding the last item in a linked list is simple. The following function I have crafted below shows how you can obtain a specific node in a linked list at a certain index:

```
NODE* getNode(NODE* start, int index)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        start = start -> next;
    }
    return start;
}
```

This code can be modified so it instead returns the last node.

```
NODE* getLastNode(NODE* start)
{
    for(;;)
    {
        start = start -> next;
        if(start -> next == NULL)
            return start;
    }
}
```

The code above traverses each node in the list until it hits one that has it's connected node as `NULL`. It then returns that last node.

Now you can call said function above and get the last node.

> set the "next" link of this item to point to the new person so the new
>   person becomes the last item in the list (i.e. the new person should
>   have a "next" link of NULL)

I'm sure you know how to do this judging from the code you provided above.

Comment: Hey Cyg! Thank you for your advice. It was really clear and straight forward. My code compiles now but for some reason I am getting a Segmentation Fault. I am getting when calling the method insert_end int i;
  for (i =0; i < HOW_MANY; i++) 
  {
    people = insert_end(people, names[i], ages[i]);
  }

Comment: By the way, I updated my code to your suggestions.

Comment: @Sarah A segmentation fault usually occurs when trying to access memory that is impossible to access. Normally, when implementing linked lists, this occurs when you try to access a member of a node that is ```NULL```. Look through your code and pay close attention to instances when you may be looping out of bounds.

Comment: @Sarah By the way, I can't pinpoint your segmentation fault error, unless I have all you code. If you want, you can email me at my email that is on my profile page.